# how xslt apply-template handles same subtree matching?

Tags: xml, xslt

Suppose I have a food.xml file

```
<food>
    <fruits>
        <fruit>apple</fruit>
        <fruit>banana</fruit>
    </fruits>
</food>
```

Now, my food.xsl is something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Errors>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Errors>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="food/fruits">
        <!-- SOME-WORK -->
        <!-- FRUITS-SUBTREE -->
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="food/fruits">
        <!-- SOME-WORK -->
        <!-- AGAIN-FRUITS-SUBTREE -->
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="food/fruits/fruit">
        <!-- SOME-WORK -->
        <!-- A-SINGLE-FRUIT-ELEMENT-IN-FRUITS-SUBTREE -->
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now, as I have noticed that the XSLT `apply-template` will skip the same subtree(`food/fruits`) or any subtree inside of it(`food/fruits/fruit`) if it has already traversed the subtree beforehand.

I can see the point of having XSLT behave this way to optimize the traversal. But my question is how to make sure if we have already used the template match for the same subtree or any subtree inside of it if my XSL file is quite big? That is how do we safely scale the number of template-rule without worrying that it may be a complete/partial overlap with another subtree?

**UPDATE:**

The main context for my question is regarding some condition checks with xml files. I have a list of conditions for my xml files to follow(the kind of checks which XSD schema can miss) and I am using XSLT 1.0 to verify those checks.

So, for me maybe I applied a template-rule for a check and suppose it completely/partially overall with some existing template-rule? How to avoid that?

**For example:**

*check1:* number of fruits should be greater than 5.

*check2:* each fruit should be unique.

and the psuedo-xsl file be like:

```
<xsl:template match="food/fruits">
    <!-- CHECK-1 -->
</xsl:template>
    
<xsl:template match="food/fruits">
    <!-- CHECK-2 -->
</xsl:template>
```

Then, there should be some way to indicate that as a WARNING that `Please merge both the template-rule` or some of the checks will not be processed?

Comment: I think you misunderstand the XSLT processing model. A node in one mode is processed by a single template, that with highest priority. There some ways in XSLT 1 to use `xsl:apply-imports` and in XSLT 2 and later to use `xsl:next-match` to "chain" matching templates but it is not clear whether you want that as you haven't shown any template content nor any sample input and wanted result.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I updated a bit, please see

Comment: Re your update: there is no need to have a separate template for each check.

Comment: It sounds to me as if you want to learn and use Schematron to specify your checks, the existing implementations like Schematron Skeleton using modes or Schxslt (at least for XSLT 2 or ) using `xsl:next-match` will then make sure all relevant checks are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me as if you are trying to reinvent and reimplement Schematron (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schematron) like rules/assertions/tests. Perhaps consider trying to learn and apply Schematron to express your validation rules (would be e.g.

```
<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" queryBinding="xslt2">
    <pattern>
        <rule context="food/fruits">
            <assert test="count(fruit) gt 5">There are less than 6 fruits.</assert>
            <assert test="count(distinct-values(fruit)) = count(fruit)">Not all fruits are unique.</assert>
        </rule>
    </pattern>
</schema>
```

), then any XSLT based implementation of Schematron would use modes (Skeleton Schematron implementation, I think) or `xsl:next-match` (Schxslt, I think) to make sure your checks are all performed.

For your own coding, in XSLT 1.0 you would need to set up modes

```
<xsl:template match="food/fruits">
    <!-- CHECK-1 -->
</xsl:template>
    
<xsl:template match="food/fruits" mode="check-2">
    <!-- CHECK-2 -->
</xsl:template>
```

and make sure you push your `fruits` through both modes with e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="food/fruits"/>` and `<xsl:apply-templates select="food/fruits" mode="check-2"/>`.

With XSLT 2 or 3 you could use `xsl:next-match`:

```
<xsl:template match="food/fruits">
    <!-- CHECK-1 -->
</xsl:template>
    
<xsl:template match="food/fruits">
    <xsl:next-match/>
    <!-- CHECK-2 -->
</xsl:template>
```